# Bootable usb from dmg taking more space than it should

Tags: macos, usb, disk-utility

I have made a bootable USB disk using a DMG and restoring it to a partition. I planned on making this USB a multiple-version recovery USB for use at a repair shop, but I can't fit everything I want onto it. The biggest issue is that each installer takes up much more space than the installer seems like it should.

On my 32 GB flash drive, 10.6 install DVD has taken up about 12 GB, when I know that writing it can be done with a DL DVD with the capacity of 8.5 GB. Disk utility reports that the DMG alone is only 7.7GB.

What's going on here to take up the additional 3.5 GB of space?

Comment: could you take look at it with "diskutil list"

Comment: That provides the size of the whole drive as I restored the only partition from the installer dmg image. Tried to erase free space, but that failed, so now I need to zero the drive and re-restore it again.

Comment: It was my understanding you had multiple partitions? and I was not aware you restored it!

Comment: I _plan_ on making multiple partitions, I haven't yet because I was going to recover to one, shrink it, add new in free space, recover the next dmg to the new partition. I haven't done so yet because of the first attempt taking more space than it should.